# Deleted user - Remove link to UserDisp or Person page

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, delete, mysite

I'm trying to figure out what removes links from Created By/ Modified By fields for a deleted user?

To elaborate I have a user who no longer exists in LDAP source, so does not exist in UPA and in site collection UserInfo table (tp_Deleted) deleted. When viewing that users documents in SharePoint 2013 - "Modified By" field links to the /UserDisp.aspx page. If clicked it throws an error message (/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=1212). For some other deleted users I'm seeing Modified By field is not linked..which would be ideal. For active users of course it take to the mysite person page.

Is there any job which removes this link? I've waited long enough (weeks) but still running into this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Basically User Profile Sync Services take care of this, If User profile sync is configured(Also MySite cleanup job), please run the incremental or full sync.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97559a3a-679d-4c7a-a709-e69b69885074/where-does-sharepoint-pull-a-users-name-for-modified-by?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Thanks Waqas for your response. I've run MySite cleanup job and Search crawls - hoping these may correct this without any luck. Not sure how UPSA Sync can help here (even though it ran few times already). As indicated that user is not present in UPA DB already (has been deleted). Any other thoughts?